# Scrapy spider index error

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

This is the code for Spyder1 that I've been trying to write within Scrapy framework:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.item import Item
from firm.items import FirmItem

class Spider1(CrawlSpider):
    domain_name = 'wc2'
    start_urls = ['http://www.whitecase.com/Attorneys/List.aspx?LastName=A']
    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=["hxs.select(
            '//td[@class='altRow'][1]/a/@href').re('/.a\w+')"]), 
            callback='parse'),
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        JD = FirmItem()
        JD['school'] = hxs.select(
                   '//td[@class="mainColumnTDa"]').re('(?<=(JD,\s))(.*?)(\d+)'
        )
        return JD    

SPIDER = Spider1()
```

The regex in the `rules` successfully pulls all the bio urls that I want from the start url:

```
>>> hxs.select(
...             '//td[@class="altRow"][1]/a/@href').re('/.a\w+')
[u'/cabel', u'/jacevedo', u'/jacuna', u'/aadler', u'/zahmedani', u'/tairisto', u
'/zalbert', u'/salberts', u'/aaleksandrova', u'/malhadeff', u'/nalivojvodic', u'
/kallchurch', u'/jalleyne', u'/lalonzo', u'/malthoff', u'/valvarez', u'/camon',
u'/randerson', u'/eandreeva', u'/pangeli', u'/jangland', u'/mantczak', u'/darany
i', u'/carhold', u'/marora', u'/garrington', u'/jartzinger', u'/sasayama', u'/ma
sschenfeldt', u'/dattanasio', u'/watterbury', u'/jaudrlicka', u'/caverch', u'/fa
yanruoh', u'/razar']
>>>
```

But when I run the code I get

```
[wc2] ERROR: Error processing FirmItem(school=[]) - 

[Failure instance: Traceback: <type 'exceptions.IndexError'>: list index out of range
```

This is the FirmItem in Items.py

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class FirmItem(Item):
    school = Field()

    pass
```

Can you help me understand where the index error occurs?

It seems to me that it has something to do with [SgmLinkExtractor](http://doc.scrapy.org/topics/link-extractors.html#sgmllinkextractor).

I've been trying to make this spider work for weeks with Scrapy. They have an excellent tutorial but I am new to python and web programming so I don't understand how for instance `SgmlLinkExtractor` works behind the scene.

Would it be easier for me to try to write a spider with the same simple functionality with Python libraries? I would appreciate any comments and help.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think it's in the LinkExtractor at all; it seems to me that it's something involved in the parse method, which searches for the school the degree is from.

Comment: Ok. Then I think, I need to add a for loop to parse so that it looks for the JD in each of the URLs returned by the LinkExtractor? But I don't really understand the relationship between LinkExtractor and parse. 

The tutorial here http://doc.scrapy.org/intro/tutorial.html#extracting-the-data has the for loop in parse but it uses nested hxs. It's not clear how I can implement that in my case, where I have only 1 regex.

Comment: Always use raw string literal for strings that might contain regexps e.g., instead of '\w+' use r'\w+'.

Comment: I put the r before the quote marks. Does it have to go next to \w+ 

rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r"/.a\w+"]), callback='parse'),)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SgmlLinkExtractor doesn't support selectors in its "allow" argument.

So this is wrong:

```
SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=["hxs.select('//td[@class='altRow'] ...')"])
```

This is right:

```
SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r"product\.php"])
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I simplified SgmLinkExtractor by writing just one name:

    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=["/aabbas"]), callback='parse'),)

but i still get the same "index out of range" error. What do I need to do make this work?

Comment: if allow doesn't allow selectors can I pass to it items from a list?

Comment: like SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=["name"])?
where name is "/aabbas"

Answer (score 0):

The parse function is called for each match of your SgmlLinkExtractor.

As Pablo mentioned you want to simplify your SgmlLinkExtractor.

Comment: Ok, as I replied to Pablo, I tried it with just one of the names /aabbas. But I still get the index out of range error. Can you help how I need to rephrase LinkExtractor to work. If it works then I may try to fine-tune it later. Thanks.

Comment: ok, so the match should be /aabbas. What does parse function gets for this match?

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to put the names scraped from the initial url into a list and then pass each name to parse in the form of absolute url as `http://www.whitecase.com/aabbas` (for /aabbas).

The following code loops over the list, but I don't know how to pass this to parse . Do you think this is a better idea?

```
baseurl = 'http://www.whitecase.com'
names = ['aabbas', '/cabel', '/jacevedo', '/jacuna', '/igbadegesin']

def makeurl(baseurl, names):
  for x in names:
      url = baseurl + x
      baseurl = 'http://www.whitecase.com'
      x = ''
      return url
```